# Will getting a new battery fix my dead Macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power

My Macbook (2017 - 12 inch) just died on me. The screen went black and it shut down without warning. I've tried all the suggestions on the Apple help website: tried different power cords, resetting the SMC etc, holding the power button for 10 seconds etc. But it's showing absolutely no signs of life.

Something that does happen though is when I have the laptop plugged into power I can feel underneath the laptop that the battery gets really really hot. Starting from being completely cool, within 15 seconds of being plugged in I can already feel the battery getting very hot. And if I leave it plugged in it keeps on getting hotter and hotter until it feels dangerously hot.

I know it's normal for batteries to get hot when being charged, but is it normal for it to get this hot while switched off and to get hot so rapidly?

If my laptop can be repaired simply by replacing the battery (around £200 in the UK I think) then this cost seems worth it compared to having to buy a new laptop.

However, the fact it's showing no signs of life and the battery gets so hot when plugged in, is making me think the problem with my laptop is deeper than just "a 3 year old worn out battery" which needs replacing. Is it more likely that the problem lies with the logic board?

Comment: Nobody can answer this definitively without inspecting your laptop.  You should take it an authorized repair center to troubleshoot and make recomendations.

Comment: Battery getting really hot on charging usually indiacates a dying / dead / defective battery. Don't charge it - the increased heat may cause further damage. Take it to Apple and let them diagnose the problem. Then decide if you want them to fix it or get it repaired from someone else or repair it yourself.